# Why do old React Native projects encounter issues?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native, and I have a question about something I want to learn. Whenever I try to open old React Native projects, I consistently encounter issues. I don't need to specify the specific problem I'm facing because it happens all the time with build settings, packages, and so on. What I'm curious about is why a project that was working perfectly three months ago is now causing problems when I try to open it. What could be causing this?

For example, is there something in the Android `build.gradle` file that has changed? Does that thing work differently between three months ago and today? Or is it possible that the packages I'm using are behaving differently? After all, the versions of packages in both the Gradle file and package.json file are fixed

Comment: Did you update any dependency of your app or it's using the same dependencies you were using when the project was working fine? Wich error is hapening when you try to build your app?

Comment: @NoNam4 I'm trying to run the original application without updating any packages. Errors like react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin, minCompileSdk etc. How can I start the project exactly as I started it in the old day when I started it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. I faced this issue several times. I believe it happens because of three reasons:

1. Native side break changes:

   It means a couple of packages on the iOS or Android sides did work, but when you try to reinstall them by `pod install` (iOS) and automatically in Android because of some new changes, they won't work at all.
2. JavaScript side break changes:

   As you know, in the `package.json` file, most of the packages are installed by the `^` or `~`, and which means some minor or patch changes would be accepted, and it can hurt the build or dev process after a while.
3. CDN packages break changes:

   Sometimes, the Native or JavaScript side tries to install something like an XML file from a CDN to have the latest changes. Still, it got completely changed or didn't even exist at all, like the `jCenter` or `maven` packages of the Facebook CDNs, which made a significant break change.

*My experience*: Even because of this issue, I had to create a new project, migrate my codes and changes there and re-install some packages from scratch. It's a common thing in the React Native world.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to do this? After all, the project was working 3 months ago. Isn't there a way to pin all external dependencies to exactly 3 months ago? In this way, the project works just like before and we do not encounter any errors.

Comment: What you asked is possible about the 1st and 2nd, but what do you do about the 3rd issue, after updates of Facebook there is no CDN for maven. You must change something, it's inevitable. @Nemesis